# FDDividendAmericanEngine Function in QuantLib

Tags: excel, quantlib, vba

How do I call Following Function:

Function: **

- **FDDividendAmericanEngine**

**

I was able to call Another function like this

```
blackScholesId = Application.Run( _

"qlGeneralizedBlackScholesProcess", "blackScholes", _

blackVolId, 36, "Actual/365 (Fixed)", 35932, 0.06, 0)
```

FDDividendAmericanEngine Function is not in the list of functions of QuantLib

[**https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibxl/allfunctions.html**](https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibxl/allfunctions.html)

But the following link seems to indicate that one can call it:

[**http://www.quanttools.com/HTMLHelp/html/CT.06069.htm**](http://www.quanttools.com/HTMLHelp/html/CT.06069.htm)

Comment: @ashleedawg and that question has been deleted.  This is at least the third incarnation of this question.  All under different names.

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for saving me the research. I've re-answered.

Comment: @ashleedawg actually it is still active: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937338/how-do-i-call-a-function-not-present-in-the-list

Comment: @ScottCraner - Frustrating.  And there was a third?  I'll FFM.

Comment: @ScottCraner possibly this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938805/file-not-found-error-at-the-compilation-stage ?

Comment: @Bhai - I'd suggest you read about how [Duplicate Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/370758) and [multiple accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35593/370758) can get you a [Question Ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).  It's a waste of time for others on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says clearly in the instructions in the link you provided:

> Within Excel, the function is named - `CT.ENG.FDDividendAmericanEngine`

This means, in Excel, **you should not use**:

```
FDDividendAmericanEngine
```

...you **should instead use**:

```
CT.ENG.FDDividendAmericanEngine
```

---

To find out how to use functions from a third-party add-in, you need to consult the products documentation (as I just did), or Google for examples of others using the product, or else contact the add-in's developer.