# Quantlib Function Calling

Tags: excel, finance, quantitative-finance, quantlib, vba

How can I call a function in Excel VBA Programming that is not present in Quantlib library?

I got the list of functions from [here](https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibxl/allfunctions.html).

I tried to call other Functions like this:

```
“qlBlackConstantVol” with "blackConstantVol",
    blackVolId = Application.Run("qlBlackConstantVol", _
        "blackConstantVol", 35932, "Target", 0.2, "Actual/365 (Fixed)")
```

I'm trying to Call `FDDividendAmericanEngine` function but couldn't find any way to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FDDividendAmericanEngine Function in QuantLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952720/fddividendamericanengine-function-in-quantlib)

Comment: Why are so many people asking essentially the same question, using almost the same wording,  within 24 hours?

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know I took it from a Forum.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sir, Kindly let me know How to Call this Function in the Answers Section. Thanks